# yii2 get latest id number

Tags: php, yii2

please help regarding this issue.

I want to get the id number after I save. I am using this method:

```
Yii::$app->db->getLastInsertID()
```

but all I have was the second to the last ID number.

Ex.: after saving the latest ID number should 115 but I got 114. I'm using it like:

```
if ($model->save()){
            Yii::$app->session['schedviewid'] = Yii::$app->db->getLastInsertID();
}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

after save you can use $model->id;

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing after saving

use `$model->refresh();` after save()

Comment: i used it like this


`if ($model->save()){

                $model->refresh();

                Yii::$app->session['schedid'] = $model->id;

            }`


but still i get previous ID

Comment: if you are saving a model that has already been created (i.e. updating) then the id will not change. If it is a new model you are save you can just use $model->id at any point after $model->save(). If for some reason what you want is to change the id then you should delete the model then save it.